# asp.net mvc 6 model binding to complex collection - IList<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, model-binding

I am trying to do a post operation in asp.net mvc 6 and expecting the complex property collection to be initialized properly. But it is always empty.

I am creating input html element with proper index:

This is an HTML FORM for POST:

```
@model MainObject
<form asp-action="create" method="post">
  <input asp-for="ChildObjects[0].RollNumber" />
  <input type="submit" value="create" />
</form>
```

Controller Code

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(MainObject mainObj)
{
    // The mainObj.ChildObjects remains empty.
}
```

My view will contain only one child object entry, that's why only 0 index used.

The form data contains the above key and value but when it reaches the controller action the collection property is empty i.e. MainObject.ChildObjects has count 0. (Note: The ChildObjects list is already initialized in my MainObject constructor)

Models:

```
public class MainObject {
   public MainObject() {
      this.ChildObjects = new List<ChildObjects>();
   }

   public IList<ChildObject> ChildObjects {get; private set;}
}
```

On looking up the ModelState property in constructor in debug mode, it shows one Error for ChildObjects key, but the error message is too generic:

> Object reference not set to instance of an object.

I have followed many articles on net for model binding complex collection, but somehow it is not working for me.

Comment: Your usage of `asp-for` is suspect, you probably want `value=Model.ChildObjects[0].RollNumber`.  But if you've got an empty reference, you need to post your controller code where you are instantiating this MainObject and forwarding it to the view also.

Comment: asp-for creates a name tag, which is expected. Value attribute is used for the actual value. Added the controller code

Comment: @StaffordWilliams `asp-for` is MVC6 (or MVC core if you like) syntax for tag helpers.

Comment: @DavigG aware, but thought that tag was supposed to be in a `<label>`, however I see [here](http://aspnetmvc.readthedocs.org/projects/mvc/en/latest/views/tag-helpers/intro.html) that it does also go in the `<input>`.

Comment: @Jash your controller action is not passing the object back to the view; ie: `return View(mainObj)`

Comment: @StaffordWilliams, the problem is not with the view not getting the data. This is a post operation, where i am creating the MainObject model. So, I am expecting the ChildObjects list to be set properly when the request reaches the controller.

Comment: @StaffordWilliams It's fine on `input` too.

Comment: @StaffordWilliams, I have update the HTML to be more precise explaining that its a form with post

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Declaring the child object collection with `private set` blocks the binder from setting the collection values.  The setter must be `public` so MVC6 can set the values in the postback;

```
public IList<ChildObject> ChildObjects {get; private set;} // empty on postback
public IList<ChildObject> ChildObjects {get; set;} // populated on postback
```

The collection is still instantiated however (rather than null, and hence `count == 0`) when the model binder calls the parameterless constructor you have declared.

Comment: Wow, so this was the issue. After removing the private setter it worked. Thanks Stafford. Aside, what if i want to have the private setter, then are there any alternatives?

Comment: @Jash You probably want it to be private due to some kind of business logic.  Don't stick business logic in your models, they should just be shells that transport the data from your controller to your view for binding.  Stick the business logic in whatever holds that data prior to you sticking it in the view.

Comment: I thought, we should always have the collections property as read only, and it has nothing to do with business logic but more of a best coding practise. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182327(VS.80).aspx

Comment: Business logic was probably the wrong term, _best practice_ is likely a better one.  However all best practices and/or patterns are at best a guide and there are cases where they do not apply.  With MVC<6 (and possibly with MVC6, i'm not certain) you _could_ write a custom model binder to hack your way around this.  However adding such complexity to what should (as mentioned earlier) be just a boring shell for transferring/binding data is going beyond the intentions of the best practice you've linked.  If models were expected to do more than just bind data, then sure, your link is valid.

Comment: @StaffordWilliams: Shouldn't it also work with a preinstantiated list in the model? i.e. using property initializers: `public IList<ChildObject> ChildObjects {get; } = new List<ChildObject>();` ?

Comment: @Tseng not sure - haven't used much C#6.  Jash could give it a shot.